# Command to print name of SSID to which I am connected

Tags: wifi, wpa-supplicant

Is there a simple command to find out to which Wi-Fi [AP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireless_access_point) I am connected?

I have several networks configured in my `/etc/wpa_supplicant.d/wpa_supplicant.conf`, with assigned priorities, and depending where I am I connect to the best available Wi-Fi/SSID. Connection happens automatically, so I don't know to which SSID I am connected.

Now I need to check (inside a script) whether I am connected at home, or somewhere else.

I know that I can list all available SSIDs with

```
iwlist wlan0 scan
```

But how can I print the SSID to which I am connected at the moment?

I am using [Debian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debian).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

How about `iwgetid`? The iwgetid(8) man page says:

> iwgetid is used to find out the NWID, ESSID or AP/Cell Address of the wireless network that is currently used.

Comment: `iwgetid wlan0 --raw` is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks.

Comment: From what I've seen so far, if the computer doesn't have Wi-Fi configured, `iwgetid` may not be installed, so that is something you may want to check first. And then if it is installed but not connected, `iwgetid --raw` will output nothing and exit with status code 255.

Answer (score 3):

None of the programs recommended in the previous answers was already installed on my system. However, `iw` was. Therefore,

```
iw dev
```

does the trick. And if you really want *just* the ssid (e.g. for a script)

```
iw dev | grep ssid | awk '{print $2}'
```

works for me.

Comment: What system are you using, in what version?

Answer (score 2):

This may work:

```
/sbin/iwconfig wlan0 | grep ESSID
```

Answer (score 0):

Searching for a solution to this for a script. Found the answer from xel worked really way except for ssid's with space so modified slightly

```
iw dev | grep ssid | awk -F 'ssid ' '{print $2}'
```

possible an abuse of the awk command.